# Matrices and power series

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, power-series

For any square matrix $A$, we can define $\sin A$ using the formal power series as follows:
\begin{equation}
\sin A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}A^{2n+1}
\end{equation}
Prove or disprove: there exists a $2\times2$ real matrix $A$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sin A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2020 \\0& 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: The power of $A$ needs to be $2n+1$.

Answer (score 4):

The relation $\, \sin(A)^2+\cos(A)^2=I$ also hold for matrices

So we would have to find a matrix for cosine such that $C^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&-4040\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ which is not possible.

Comment: That looks promising. What is the argument that supports the claim  $C^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&-4040\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not possible?

Comment: Just start with $C=(a,b,c,d)$ and compute $C^2$ you need to set $a=d=0$ you'll notice then upper coeff is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

\begin{equation}
B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2020 \\0& 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

is not diagonalizable. If it was $1$ would be the only eigenvalue and $B$ would be equal to the identity matrix.

Therefore if $\sin A = B$, $A$ isn't diagonalizable either. The (complex) Jordan normal form of $A$ would be

\begin{equation}
\overline A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\0& \lambda\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And

\begin{equation}
\sin \overline A=\begin{bmatrix}\sin \lambda & \cos \lambda \\0& \sin \lambda\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Hence $\lambda$ belongs to $\pi/2 + 2\pi \mathbb Z$  and

\begin{equation}
\sin \overline A=\begin{bmatrix}\sin \lambda & 0 \\0& \sin \lambda\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0& 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

is diagonalizable. A contradiction.

Comment: Wouldn't we get $\cos(\lambda)$ for the upper right entry of $\sin(\overline{A})$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes you're right! Answer updated.

Comment: But this kills the problem :)

Comment: Yes... I saw that and updated to a true answer!

Answer (score 2):

Does this help!?:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \implies B=A^n=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \implies \sin A=\begin{bmatrix} \sin 1 & \cos 1 \\ 0 & \sin 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Use $$\sin A= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: I have edited my answer you may see it again.

Comment: This answer is still irrelevant. I think this is one of the rare instances that the *upvoters* should explain why they upvoted. How on earth does this answer help?